# Task concurrency parameter in Presto configuration of EMR

Tags: configuration, amazon-emr, presto

In what EMR directory is located the Presto `task.concurrency` parameter?

Comment: Not sure about presto but I guess configuration file will be similar to spark/tez look a file `/etc/presto/conf/presto-site.xml`. But Im not entirely sure

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, I found that is located in `etc/presto/conf/config.properties`